# Tuple type in rest arguments can not downcast?

Tags: typescript

```
type Func<T extends Record<string, any>> = (
  ...args: {
    [K in keyof T]: [item: T[K], key: K, map: T];
  }[keyof T]
) => void;
```

The `Func` type can only accpect `(item,key,map)=>void`,but can't accpect `(item)=>void` or `(item,key)=>void`. How to solve this problem?

Comment: How is the type used?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgrgOwMYB4AqUIA9gQQEwGcoAlCJAewCd8VDgqBLBAcwBooBDBEAPl6gBeKAAoAUFCgA6GZyotCALigBvCZKgBtANJRmUANYQQFAGZQ0AXWWbGuALbK0OyxyMhl2jvc5gnlgG51AF9NdzMLSzEASiEBADcKRnwoAB9REVjBBKT8aKCxSgR6KFNEJABGZXhkFBUuZQQ4ewAjCCoOFuV6JlYoYIFhETsIeyyBeuDCimLgUvKAJmryuoaoJtb2zu6GZhZ+wdER+zdjb19x1X6gA

Comment: I guess you opened [ms/TS#48663](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48663) about this.  Assuming you see traction there, could you write up your own answer to this question with the results of that issue?

Answer (score 1):

You could use optionals to allow fewer values in the tuple as follows:

```
type Func<T extends Record<string, any>> = (
  ...args: {
    [K in keyof T]: [item: T[K], key?: K, map?: T?];
  }[keyof T]
) => void;
```

Comment: It's not working. In essence,the problem is that `[item:T[K],key:K,map:T]` can't downcast to `[item:T[K]]`

Comment: Does the following work for you? If so I will update my answer:
type Func<T extends Record<string, any>> = (
  ...args: [item: T[keyof T], key?: keyof T, map?: T]
) => void | (() => void);

Comment: No, It can not inference item type by key.